# prevent heading row of second QUERY range from populating when using two data ranges (OR) dynamically combining data from two sheets into a third

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

When using two data ranges in QUERY to search two sheets in the same spreadsheet with vertical stacking (curly braces around ranges of single QUERY function), the header row of the second sheet appears in the results. Is it possible to have this not occur?

This does not occur when using specific parameters avoid this (e.g., me!B2) as the heading rows don't meet the criteria.

```
=QUERY({pData;cData},"SELECT * WHERE Col2 contains 'me'")
```

This occurs when using a generic "where Col# is not null" in the QUERY (test!A1).

```
=QUERY({pData;cData},"select * where Col2 is not null",1)
```

The goal is to have a sheet that dynamically displays all content from two sheets on a third with one set of headings from one function.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E7EGjK-YuVBxgdX5URnzZMDOwvF6oAi7ZJxY9HmySNc/edit?usp=sharing

Currently, my workaround involves removing the heading rows from the query and using a separate function to generate headings (will post as an answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove both formulas and use

```
=QUERY({past!A1:E;current!A2:E},"select * where Col2 is not null", 1)
```

and see if that works?

Comment: Thank you for your response; this did work. I still have some curiosities about the solution as the named ranges are set to be exactly these identified ranges.

Perhaps this is simply a limitation of using named ranges.

Comment: As long as the first named range includes the header row, you should be okay.

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed that the second range omits its header row. This makes complete sense; while I had hoped to avoid this, it appears I'll need to build another set of dynamic ranges to accommodate this based on omitting the header rows of subsequent ranges when using multiple. Many thanks!

Comment: I guess somehting like this should work too: =QUERY({pData;cData},"select * where Col2 <> 'person' and Col2 <>''",1)

Answer (score 0):

Current workaround uses separate formulas in workaround!A1:A2. I'm still interested in potentially achieving this with one formula.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(current!A1:1)

=QUERY({past!A2:E;current!A2:E},"select * where Col2 is not null",0)
```